# Why does SFINAE not work when I use an equivalent false expression but work when I use an equivalent but slightly different one?

Tags: c++

I was trying to find a way to disable a template class instance for types that could be an alias to another depending on compile time settings.  It complained that the type has already been defined, which is in my mind weird as the type shouldn't have been instantiated in the first place:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using myint1 = int;
using myint2 = int;

enum enabler_t { enabled };
template <typename T
    , typename ENABLER = enabler_t
>
struct A;

template <>
struct A <int>
{
    A() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T
    , std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same<T, int>::value
            && std::is_same<T, myint1>::value
        , enabler_t
    >
>
{
    A() { std::cout << "myint1" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T
    , std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same<T, int>::value
            && std::is_same<T, myint2>::value
        , enabler_t
    >
>
{
    A() { std::cout << "myint2" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
    struct B {};

int main()
{
    A<int> z1;
    A<myint1> z2;
    A<myint2> z3;
}
```

<kbd>[VC++ Demo](https://rextester.com/XEVA72989)</kbd>

This isn't limited to VC++, it also happens on [clang](https://rextester.com/YHZMK91858) and [gcc](https://rextester.com/SYHTN90337). Why does this occur?

However, if I modify the expression slightly that doesn't change the result, it works fine:

```
//Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using myint1 = int;
using myint2 = int;

enum enabler_t { enabled };
template <typename T
    , typename ENABLER = enabler_t
>
struct A;

template <>
struct A <int>
{
    A() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T
    , std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same<T, int>::value
            && std::is_same<T, myint1>::value
            && 1
        , enabler_t
    >
>
{
    A() { std::cout << "myint1" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T
    , std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same<T, int>::value
            && std::is_same<T, myint2>::value
            && 2
        , enabler_t
    >
>
{
    A() { std::cout << "myint2" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
    struct B {};

int main()
{
    A<int> z1;
    A<myint1> z2;
    A<myint2> z3;
}
```

<kbd>[VC++ Demo](https://rextester.com/OWBKEF22164)</kbd><kbd>[clang Demo](https://rextester.com/BLRC21781)</kbd><kbd>[gcc Demo](https://rextester.com/LMPX35037)</kbd>

Although I use `int`s here and `using`s to define the other types, this actually has to do with function pointers of different calling conventions, which can change across compiler settings (x86 vs x64).  I only used this as a more simplified demo, where I could change things around.

Comment: Both, `myint1` and `myint2` are aliases to `int`. Both templates are exactly the same.

Comment: Use `enum class myint1 : int {};` instead of `using`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, not my choice.  These are defined by the compiler.  I used `int`s only as a simplification.

Comment: Your second example is "ill-formed, no diagnostic required", which is another way to say "undefined behavior".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, I was afraid of that.  Can you post the part of the standard that states that?

Comment: @tkausl, yes I know that.  Please reread the question.

Comment: @Adrian http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#7.sentence-3 . Can't find where the spec requires the template-id of different partial specializations to be non-equivalent, but I think that's obvious, since equivalent names have the same linkage-name, and therefore the two partial specializations would conflict when linking the program together.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, that would only be if there were multiple instantiated class templates.  However, since they didn't get instantiated because the substitution failed, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Adrian no. The specializations need to be non-equivalent. And they  are functionally equivalent but not equivalent in your second example so the program is ill-formed, no diagnostics required. This analysis comes on the definition of the specialization, before instantiations if you will. You program would be ill-formed even if no instantiations were present.

Comment: @Adrian no, you cannot declare templates with the same name twice, irrespective of whether they are instantiated. And partial specializations are template declarations themselfs aswell, their name is a `template-id`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, `If the validity or meaning of the program depends on whether two constructs are equivalent, and they are functionally equivalent but not equivalent, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.` As the meaning of the programme does not depend on if the two constructs are equivalent, this programme is not ill formed.  The meaning of the programme depends on if the two are not equivalent.  Subtle but important difference.

Comment: @bolov, what do you mean by functionally equivalent? Do they have the same API?  Maybe.  Do they do the same things?  Maybe not.

Comment: functionally equivalent but not equivalent (in this context): `true && 1` and `true && 2`

Comment: "Rule: if a final exam depends on attending the class a student cannot cannot take the final exam if he/she had no attendance. Reasoning: The french final exam depends on non-attending the class, I have not attended class, thus the rule doesn't apply" Your important difference is not much of a difference....

Comment: @bolov, where is that quote from?  I'm having difficulty parsing it.  Can't tell if ambiguous or nonsensical.

Comment: @Adrian it is a construct I made up to illustrate how your phrase about "depending on non-equivalent" is nonsensical.